# mod rewrite - query parameter not handled properly

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here are my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.(html?|php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^info/db$ info/db/index.php?kid=7 [L]
RewriteRule ^info/db/general$ info/db/general.php?kid=15 [L]
```

When I type in the URL `www.mypage.com/info/db`, the query parameter isn't recognized ($_GET doesn't contain anything).

However, when I click on a link in my site leading to the same page, the query string is recognized and I can access it via $_GET. But the URL in browser window is shown as `www.mypage.com/info/db/?kid=7`.

Why is this happening? Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

Test .htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc_([0-9]+)$ abc.php?kid=$1 [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^folder/abc_([0-9]+)$ folder/abc.php?kid=$1 [NC, L]
RewriteRule ^folder$ folder/index.php?kid=2 [NC,L]
```

I call u.php, which contains this:

```
<a href="abc_123">KLICK</a>
```

All works fine.

I click on the link and in the URL bar it says:

```
http://localhost/mystuff/abc_123
```

And `123` is echoed on the page, as it should:

```
<?php

echo $_GET["kid"];

?>
```

When I enter `http://localhost/mystuff/abc_123` directly, it works, as well.

When I enter `http://localhost/mystuff/folder/abc_123` directly, `123` is displayed  on the page, as it should.

When I call `http://localhost/mystuff/folder`, the query string is passed and echoed on the page, as it should, but the URL bar shows:

```
http://localhost/mystuff/folder/?kid=2
```

The rewrite rules are the only thing I have in that .htaccess right now.

Comment: i cant reproduce your problem. all works fine. Query is passed. To see it in browser write `[L,R]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting `http://localhost/mystuff/folder/?kid=2` because `folder` is a real directory and a trailing slash is being added by `mod_dir` module after `mod_rewrite` has run.

You can insert this new rule just below `RewriteEngine` to force a trailing slash for directories:

```
# add a trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mystuff/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hello! It still doesn't work. The ?kid=2 is still shown in the URL.

Comment: Add `DirectorySlash Off` on top of your .htaccess and **test it after clearing your browser**

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot!! Could you explain in more detail, what exactly was the problem? What do you mean, folder is a real directory?

Comment: If a request is made for a directory *without a trailing slash* then `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash and it does after `mod_rewrite` module. `mod_dir` also does a full redirect using `R=301`